# difference of unique values between two corresponding columns

Tags: r

I have ride start station name and their corresponding ride start station id.
But the summary data in R shows that I have 625 unique values of ride start station name and 622 for ride start station id. why is this difference and how to resolve it using R ?

Comment: Hi Danish, A bit more information on your issue and especially an example of your data using dput would be nice. There is two possibilities, either you have repetitive ID for different start station name, either some of the station, even though being the same, have slightly different name. for instance "London" ≠ "london".

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the index of the duplicated values using the following command:

```
which(duplicated(data$column))
```

Let me know if this works!